# forEach returns data multiple times

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

This code basically reads a file with test data from another directory, then takes out the "token" object from each array and pushes it into a new array (arr), then for each object, it is supposed to return the info from the info.json file that is under a specific directory.

So for example, if token is 123, it goes to '../testing/testing_info/123/info.json' and then reads the json file. I then want the script to return all of the contents in the various json files in one array.

This is what the result looks like now:

```js
[ '1', '0' ]
[
  '1',
  '0',
  '2',
  '0'
]
[
  '1',
  '0',
  '2',
  '0',
  '3',
  '-14.05'
]

Desired Result: 
 [
  '1',
  '0',
  '2',
  '0',
  '3',
  '-14.05'
]
```

```js
fs.readFile('../testing/test.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {

  let arr = [];
  var json_parse = JSON.parse(data)
  for (var i = 0; i < json_parse.length; i++) {
    arr.push(json_parse[i].token)
  }
  var arr2 = []
  arr.forEach((function(item) {
    var results_max = []

    fs.readFile('../testing/testing_info/' + item + "/info.json", 'utf8', function(err, data) {

      var parse = JSON.parse(data)

      var response_string = JSON.stringify(data)
      var response_clean = response_string.replace(/["\"[\\%\"\\\}"\""]+/g, '')
      var response_split = response_clean.split(',')

      var contract_address = response_split[1].split(':')[1]
      var percent_change = response_split[6].split(':')[1]

      arr2.push(contract_address, percent_change)
      results_max.push(percent_change)
      var x_max = Math.max(...results_max)

      console.log(arr2)
    });
  }));
});
```

The code mostly works, the problem is that I want to have a way to access the final array, with all of the data in it. Right now therte are 3 info.json files so it logs the array three sepperate times, with each time adding data from the next json file to the array, so eventually, I get the desired output, however, it logs the data three separate times.

I tried to add this to fix it:

```js
if (arr2.length == arr.length) {
  console.log(arr2)
}
```

but this didn't work either. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @JoshG for cleaning up my code.

I was able to solve this issue, I was simply overlooking something very simple.

```js
if (arr2.length == arr.length) {
  console.log(arr2)
}
```

The code above works, but it didn't work for me since arr2 and arr1 had different formats and arr2 would always have a length more than arr so it didn't work.